# VimWiki - creating markdown files compatible with VimTex - a setup for math notes

Tags: vim, latex

Ok

I've read this thread:

https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/69

They're talking about the possibility to convert VimWiki files to LaTeX. This is close to what i'm trying to create in the world of note-taking setups.

What i want is a feature where you have VimWiki as your main index of your note for a class (let's say math), and then can tab in/tab out and create new files where VimTex runs* using VimWikis FollowLink function.

** My VimTex runs in markdown files*

An example of a math_index.md for understanding:

```
# MATH NOTES
 - [[Link to this subject]] - description
 - [[Link to that subject]] - description
.. and so on
```

Then you follow a link to a file that supports [VimTex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) where you can write your in depth notes.

They are both working perfectly (VimWiki and VimTex) when i try them separately. But can i combine them?

---

What i've tried:

#### 1.

I've read about changing the file extension (for the child-file) on the fly [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Add/change_file_extension_in_current_buffer) with `:saveas %:p:r.tex`. Then you could have VimWiki creating a normal `.md` file and then remap a command changing it to `.tex` for example, but then (of course) the tabbing back and fourth will not work (it's a mess!).

Is it possible to configure the link options so it's not looking for the extension of the file? Then this would work.

#### 2.

VimTex is working with `.md` files but then :WikiFollowLink can't be called when working in the math_index.md file.

My `.vimrc`, so `.md` files have VimTex:

```
autocmd FileType,BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=tex
```

If i try setting two filetypes with `autocmd ... filetype=tex.wiki` it is shown when calling `:set ft?` on a `.md` file, but the VimWiki functionality is gone. And also - the local command :VimwikiFollowLink can't be triggered. Error when trying: Not an editor command.

I can't seem to figure out how to get this local command to work in a `filetype=tex.wiki` environment.

#### 3

I've found that VimTex (in their help) has a debugging tool reloading every plugin using for their functionality: `:VimtexReload` so i thought just going back to plain VimWiki `.md` setup and then reloading the VimTex in a child file when necessary. But **again** i'm bound by the command and can't call it in the `.md` file.

---

I'm starting in three days (math notes comming up!) :) and would really appreciate any help.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work! 
¨

#### Change another plugin a little

Okay, so there is a small vim plugin called [Vim Markdown Wiki](https://github.com/mmai/vim-markdown-wiki) that is doing the basics of VimWiki - creating file on Enter in an index.file.

I thought that it would be easier to trigger into creating tex files instead of md files.

I changed line 90 in the plugin's file: `vim-markdown-wiki/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`

From:

`let extension = fnamemodify(cur_file_name, ":e")`

To:

`let extension = "tex"`

Now it creates `.tex` files instead of `.md` files, when you use it.

Bot how to add the functionality to both .md (markdown) and .tex (LaTeX) files?

#### Create a new syntax and add it to both!

As you can see from before the file in Vim Markdown Wiki that i've changed is called `markdown.vim` so its local commands are only added to markdown files (.md).

So. I had a real problem here. How do i add the functionality to both filetypes without ruining some syntax features.

**My own syntax!** I changed the filename in my now forked plugin ([repo](https://github.com/peterhoejlundandersen/vim-markdown-wiki)) to links.vim and added that filetype to both filetypes in my `.vimrc`:

`autocmd FileType,BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead (*.md|*.tex) set filetype+=.links`'

#### Success!

Now i can use the regularly shortcuts for VimWiki, if i want to create a markdown file **AND** i can use the new plugins shortcut - i've set mine in `.vimcr`:

```
nmap z<CR> :MdwiGotoLink<cr>
nmap x<CR> :MdwiReturn<cr>
```

If i want to create a `.tex` document with LaTeX support.

Greeeat!!!